# c# ProtoBuf serializer new types

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am using *Protobuf-net* to replace my `DataContractSerializer`, but is it possible to send other object types like `Color`, `Size`, `Point` and maybe more? Because this is possible with the `DataContractSerializer`. I could not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, note that a *lot* of types can be handled automatically as "tuples"; for example, I would expect `System.Windows.Point` to work fine, because it only has a `X` and `Y`, and it has a constructor that takes `x` and `y`. Unfortunately, `System.Drawing.Point` has `X`, `Y` and `IsEmpty`, and a constructor that takes `x` and `y`, so it can't automatically deduce the correct handling of `System.Drawing.Point` - but the *point* (hah) I'm trying to make there is that : some external types will work without any extra work.

For the rest, there are various ways of approaching the issue of types outside of your domain model, using the `RuntimeTypeModel` API. Depending on the specific type, either:

- tell it how you want it to serialize that type in terms of its members
- write a surrogate for that type (with appropriate conversion operators), and tell it about the surrogate

For example:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(System.Drawing.Point), false)
                        .Add("X", "Y");
```

which configures `X` as field 1, `Y` as field 2. The surrogate approach is more useful for *complicated* scenarios, but as a trivial example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PointDto
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int X { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int Y { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(PointDto value)
    {
        return value == null
            ? System.Drawing.Point.Empty
            : new System.Drawing.Point(value.X, value.Y);
    }
    public static implicit operator PointDto(System.Drawing.Point value)
    {
        return new PointDto { X = value.X, Y = value.Y };
    }
}
```

then:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(System.Drawing.Point), false)
                        .SetSurrogate(typeof(PointDto));
```

with *this* configuration, the library will convert to/from the surrogate type as needed - the idea being that you can add whatever code you need to in the `operator`s, allowing the DTO to be very simple and opbvious to serialize.

Finally, note that many types will have a `Parse` API that works with their `ToString` implementation; if you want to enable use of the `Parse` methods (serializing as a string as a last-ditch effort), then:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AllowParseableTypes = true;
```